# Удалить ненужные файлы из образа OpenWRT

Tags: linux, embedded, openwrt, кросс-компиляция

Собираю свою прошивку через SDK OpenWRT, всё классно, но так как не использую `procd` - хочу удалить init-скрипты, которые поставляются с пакетами `openwrt` и часть из них заменить своими.

Но при упаковке в `squashfs` не исполняются скрипты `preinstall postinstall` так как `opkg` я также не использую. Не хватает возможностей чтоб патчить каждый пакет.

Есть ли какой-то хук, который исполнится перед упаковкой `rootfs`. Если изменять сильно тулчейн, то я не смогу потом обновиться...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

смотрите раздел [кастомизация целевой файловой системы](http://downloads.openwrt.org/docs/buildroot-documentation.html#custom_targetfs).

после полной сборки вы можете повторить шаг `make target_install`, внеся перед этим изменения в файловую систему, которая располагается в каталоге `build_ARCH/root/` (где `ARCH` — архитектура, например, `mipsel`).

Comment: хороший вариант, спасибо